# Git: is there a symbolic ref for the index/staging area?

Tags: git

I can use `git show rev:path/to/file` to output the a file as it was in
`rev`, and I would like a `rev` that points at the staging area. For example:

- `git show HEAD:myfile > myfile.local` will cat myfile as it is in the checked-out commit.
- `git show MERGE_HEAD:myfile > myfile.other` will cat myfile as it is in the donating branch during a merge.
- `git show XXX:myfile > myfile.staged` will cat myfile as it is in the staging area.

My question refers to the last bullet point: is there a symbolic ref XXX that refers to the staged version, or is there no such ref?

(FWIW: I have not found anything in `git help revisions`, `git help show`, on Stack Overflow, or via search engines. I'd like to get some corroboration, though, before I conclude something so obviously useful doesn't exist (and that I must propose it on Git's mailing list). Many thanks in advance!)

Comment: (This *is* what you were looking for, right?)

Comment: This is indeed the answer I was looking for, thank you! If this question is closed as a duplicate, will it stick around as a redirect to the existing question? The questions are quite differently phrased, although the answer answers both questions.

Comment: Yep, it will. Duplicates are good.